# Why are topocentric coordinates of point A relative to point B not strictly the negative of the topocentric coordinates of point B relative to point A

Tags: coordinate-system, cartesian, geographiclib, cartconvert, topocentric

I just tried to play around with some geodesy lately, using [CartConvert](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/CartConvert.1.html) in bash:

```
$ echo -43.4242920E -22.9145118N 0 | CartConvert -l -43.7954220E -22.7454621N 0
38072.841396 -18768.489365 -141.336023
```

But if I if I exchange the coordinates given in CartConvert, the result is not exactly the opposite:

```
$ echo -43.7954220E -22.7454621N 0 | CartConvert -l -43.4242920E -22.9145118N 0
-38119.890905 18672.743845 -141.335023
```

If we reverse the sign of the two first topocentric coordinates and make a subtraction, some differences appear (here in Python):

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array([38119.890905, -18672.743845, -141.335023]) -
      np.array([38072.841396, -18768.489365, -141.336023]))
[4.7049509e+01 9.5745520e+01 1.0000000e-03]
```

47 and 96 meters eastwards and northwards respectively.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local cartesian coordinate systems in CartConvert have their X axis towards the East, Y axis towards the North, and Z axis towards the "up" direction normal to the ellipsoid (this system is also called the ENU frame, for East North Up). Their orientation in space depends on the location of the chosen origin point. Therefore, the coordinates are not reversible in the way you described. The distance between the origin and the other point will remain the same, but the contributions of the X, Y, and Z axes are not necessarily the same.

```
sqrt((38072.841396)^2 + (-18768.489365)^2 + (-141.336023)^2) = 42447.819978
sqrt((-38119.890905)^2 + (18672.743845)^2 + (-141.335023)^2) = 42447.819978
```

As you can see, both distances are the same, which is a good sign. Only the values of x, y and z differ slightly because of the different spatial orientations used.

Let's add a visual example to better explain this difference.

I created two points P1, P2 near the Earth's surface and drew their local coordinate system (x, y, z) axes:

[image]

As you can see, the orientation of the local coordinate system's axes are relative to the East, North, and Up directions of *each corresponding point*.

Now let's use an orthographic perspective, and position ourselves exactly on top of P1. This is analogous to evaluating the X and Y values in you first conversion. If we look at the position of P2 from P1's perspective, we notice large positive values for X and Y (see dotted black lines):

[image]

Now let's do the same with P2 (2nd conversion):

[image]

Notice how the contributions of the X and Y axes are very different, and aren't simply reversed in their sign. We have a large negative x value, and a small positive y value!

This example is exaggerated by using very large distances of course, but the same principle holds for smaller distances too, and that accounts for the small differences that you observed. You can try to run your code with two points very far from each other, and notice how the X and Y values are wildly different from what you originally expected. You may even notice a more significant difference in the Z values as well, since the Earth is a spheroid and not a perfect sphere.

There are some very specific cases where the X and Y values *would* be simply reversed, for example, if both points were on the Equator, then the x value would be reversed in sign, the Y value would be 0, and the Z value would be the same, because the Equator is modelled as a perfect circle.

Comment: Fantastic answer and very educational, thank you, I wasn't expecting such nice drawings. Btw, I'm curious, what tool did you used to make these?

Comment: You're welcome! I used Blender to generate the 3D graphics.